# CSS background-color problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to refactor my CSS down, combining redundant elements and trimming unnecessary code (I am taking a mobile apps course that focuses on creating web-based hybrid apps; using HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript. Thus, the code must be refactored). What I originally had was:

```
body
{
    width: 400px;
    border: solid;
}

header, footer
{
    background-color: #ADDFFF;
}

.buttons
{
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ADDFFF;
}
```

Which would use an HTML structure like this:

```
<BODY>
   <header>
   </header>
   <div class="buttons">
   </div>
   <footer>
   </footer>
</BODY>
```

I tried adding in  `background-color: #ADDFF;`  into the body CSS and removing the all the rest of the  `background-color`  references. When I do that, the entirety of the page becomes the color I set; which I half expected. Is there anyway, without redundant use of CSS elements, to set the background of the body to encompass just the area that is displayed by the page?

Simple / TL;DR version:

I am trying to make the whole background of the page the same color. Currently just styling the    tag causes the entire background (also outside of my page) to be colored.

Comment: remove the div in the footer and change it to </footer> also can you simply your question. If im not mistaking then you are tying to add different colors to your divs?

Comment: By "just the area that is displayed by the page" do you mean those parts of `body` that aren't overlapped by other elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a different `bakground-color` for the `html` element. This will force the body to only affect its contents and not the whole page..

```
html
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

body
{
    width: 400px;
    border: solid;
    background-color: #ADDFFF;
}

.buttons
{
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SsFsS/

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is what you can do is surround EVERYTHING in a div that contains the header, content, and footer.  Make it be the width you want the page to be the height should be filled by the content.  Then make the background of that the color you want.

```
<BODY>
    <div id="container">
       <header>
       </header>
       <div class="buttons">
       </div>
       <footer>
       </footer>
    </div>
</BODY>
```

So the container won't be the whole width of the page.  It will only be as wide as the content is.

here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/pRwMn/1/

So you can set a default background and then you can change the background of all other elements as needed

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
body > * { background-color: #ADDFFF; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<header> and <footer>` are just guidelines and don't have the same effect as `<body>`

what you'll need to do is have something like the following.

```
body
{
    width: 400px;
    border: solid;
}

header, footer
{
    background-color: /* change here as necessary */;
}

.buttons
{
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: /* change here as necessary */;
}

#container 
{
    background-color: #addfff;
}
```

and then your html doc should read like this

```
<BODY>
   <header>
   </header>
   <div id="container">
      <div class="buttons">
      </div>
   </div>
   <footer>
   </footer>
</BODY>
```